# Does Wake-on-LAN work with non-integrated ethernet adapters?

Tags: hardware, ethernet, wake-on-lan

Interested in the information presented for this question: [Turn on Home Computer Remotely](https://serverfault.com/questions/5931/turn-on-home-computer-remotely) but I'm wondering if I absolutely need to use a motherboard integrated adapter in order to accomplish it. Have you had success employing WOL using a PCI adapter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen Wake-on-LAN advertised on PCI NIC cards way back when 100MB Ethernet was fairly new at the desktop. Back then, integrated network cards were not yet standard (but becoming so). That said, WoL for non-integrated components is a function of BIOS support. It needs to keep enough power on the peripheral bus, whatever you're using, and needs to allow devices on that bus to issue wake-up events. It can be done, but I'm not sure how common BIOS support is these days.

Answer (score 8):

As far as I'm aware you need to run a cable from the WoL NIC to the motherboard.

Answer (score 5):

I find that it depends a lot more on the motherboard then the network adapter when using addon cards.  I have seen it work with Intel and 3Com cards.

Answer (score 3):

If it's a card it needs to have a WoL connector cable that connects it to the motherboard.